# A fighter for change, for over four hundred years!

Tags: riddle

> Almost five hundred years ago, I fought for change.
>
> Over four centuries later, now a King, 
>  I again fought change, but now on a completely different area.
>
> However, my roots are still the same.

Who am I?

Comment: Is this riddle expected to change with time?

Comment: @me_digvijay No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I certainly hope it's

> Martin Luther... King Jr. Martin Luther started the Reformation movement in the 1500s. Martin Luther King Jr. (now a king) fought to end discrimination in the United States four hundred years later. They had a common theological perspective, hence the reference to roots.

Comment: That is correct.